# ¿Cuál sería una buena traducción para "self-fulfilling prophecy"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

"[Self-fulfilling prophecy](https://www.britannica.com/topic/self-fulfilling-prophecy)" es una expresión que se usa en inglés para referirse a una predicción que se cumple porque la gente actúa de manera diferente al oír que la predicción ha sido hecha. El ejemplo que pone la Enciclopedia Britannica es el de predecir que muchos bancos van a quebrar, lo cual crea pánico en la gente, que corre a los bancos a sacar su dinero, haciéndolos quebrar de verdad.

En el DLE, las entradas para [profecía](https://dle.rae.es/profec%C3%ADa) y [predicción](https://dle.rae.es/predicci%C3%B3n) no incluyen ninguna expresión con este significado. En [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=self-fulfilling%20prophecy%2C), encuentro traducciones que no me convencen mucho, como "profecía autocumplida", "profecía autorrealizada", o traducciones que son correctas pero demasiado largas/explicativas, como "profecía que contribuye a su propio cumplimiento".

¿Hay alguna expresión con este significado en español?

Comment: Ah, pues yo al ver el título directamente había pensado en "profecía autocumplida", juraría que la he oído en más de una ocasión. ¿Por qué no te convence?

Comment: Coincido con Charlie, el término normal para eso es "profecía autocumplida", y es de uso corriente. Por qué no te cuadra?

Comment: @Charlie Vaya, no me convence porque no lo he oído nunca ni lo he encontrado en los diccionarios. Debe ser entonces cosa mía solamente...

Comment: Para mí también es "profecía autocumplida". Traducción literal o casi, por supuesto, pero no hay nada de malo en eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las tres traducciones posibles son: Profecía Autocumplida, Profecía Autorrealizada y Autoprofecía.

Si buscas en google cualquiera de las tres expresiones, verás que aparecen en muchas páginas, textos, e incluso medios de comunicación como radio, televisión y prensa. Por tanto, son expresiones que están asentadas en el español.

Incluso en la wikipedia tienes una entrada: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profec%C3%ADa_autocumplida

También puedes usar la expresión "El efecto Pigmalión" (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efecto_Pigmali%C3%B3n). Aunque no es exactamente lo mismo.